# Is Diablo 3 Dodge chance random or consistent?

Tags: diablo-iii

On my Monk, I'm trying to figure out if I would rather do a Dodge build with Dodge-centered Passives and Mantras, or if I should go for more armor and healing. In my mind, it comes down to just how random Dodge is.

**If I have a 50% dodge rate, which of these is true?**

1. Every time I am attacked, I have a 50% chance to Dodge the attack.
2. Incoming attacks will be Dodged at a consistently 50% rate. Past results affect future results - eg, I have not Dodged in a while, I will be more likely to Dodge.

Essentially I am asking if the [Gambler's Fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy) is true for Dodge chance.

Both case #1 and case #2 would average out to the same thing in a long fight, but in a short burst case #2 is preferable.

In case #1, a string of bad randomness will mean I could take several hits in a row without Dodging any of them (Dodge, Dodge, Dodge, Hit, Hit, Hit, Hit, Hit, Hit owww my spleen). If that happens, my Dodge wasn't really much use to me, as a bunch of unfortunate die rolling got me killed.

In case #2, having 50% Dodge chance is nearly equivalent to 50% damage mitigation, as attacks would essentially alternate (Dodge, Hit, Dodge, Hit, Dodge, Hit, Dodge, Hit). I can expect that I will consistently avoid incoming attacks, and don't have to curse `Math.Rand()` for getting me killed.

So, which is it? Can I expect consistent results from my Dodging, or is it all chance?

Comment: I know case 2 was used in Warcraft 3, another Blizzard game, for figuring out certain proc effects. It wouldn't surprise me if it was used again, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: @StrixVaria in WoW case 1 is used.

Comment: @Blem since you mention WoW, I'll mention that at some patch case 2 was implemented for several aspects of the game (most prominently quest item drops)... just some trivia. Mag Roader: This is Diablo, so it's all about random.

Comment: Case 2 is known as "pseudo-random". "The generation of random numbers is too important to leave to chance."

Comment: @StrixVaria In Warcraft 3 I remember the blademaster critting 3 or 4 times in a row for a total bullshit effet

Comment: @Eric It wasn't exactly normalized in WC3. It just increased in probability with every failure until it was guaranteed. You could still get lucky, you just couldn't get unlucky.

Comment: @Raven: All randomness in a computer is technically pseudorandom, so the answer to the new question is necessarily *"it's pseudorandom."*  This is not what OP was asking, though, so the original term *"consistent"* was a much better choice.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Granted, but there's still a difference between calling C's rand every time, and changing the thresholds based on the previous rand calls. Using past results to ensure a more uniform random distribution is known as pseudorandom in games like this.

Comment: @Raven: Source?  I have *never* heard this referred to as "pseudorandom" - you are actually making the distribution significantly *less* random in order to eliminate winning/losing streaks.  See also [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11217/)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The article I found refers to it as ["Pesudo-Random Distribution"](http://www.create-games.com/article.asp?id=1957)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since one of the Monk's achievements ([Like Water](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/like-water)) is to dodge 15 attacks in a row, I would say #1 is accurate: each time you are attacked you have a 50% change to dodge

This can further be backed up by many dodge-specced monks who can testify to dying many times due to a string of bad luck :)

Comment: I had this feeling yesterday fighting Belial as Monk. I died once after a really unlucky streak of dodge not proccing.

Comment: Other reasons to guess that case #1 is true is that from a programmer's perspective, case #1 is far easier to implement, and is far less likely to have math bugs that accidentally make players nigh-invulnerable, or walking pincushions!

Comment: @Wikwocket, I doubt implementing either method would cause a first year college student any problems.

Comment: @oscode Have you met many first year college students? Besides, after seeing WoW Rogues achieve 100% dodge through creative use of game mechanics, I can imaging Blizzard being conservative here. :)

Comment: Possible implementation: count # of incoming attacks and dodged attacks. If count is 0, randomly dodge, otherwise take  #dodges/#attacks, and either dodge or not depending on whether the result would be closer to or farther away from your dodge%. If desired, reset the values occasionally, say after 5 seconds of no incoming attacks.

Comment: @Wikwocket, for a big-name title like Diablo, they are not going to skimp and choose a less-than-preferable solution simply because it's an easier programming problem (especially in this case, where both problems are pretty trivial to solve). In the general case, they will put in the extra money/time/manpower to make it work how they want, even for the hard problems.

Comment: @Ben Lee and others: Good points of course. My initial comment was mostly facetious. But it's often true, when programming a complicated piece of software, that simpler is better. =)

Comment: @Wikwocket, I can't argue with that! In most software development, it really is a trade-off between development costs and features. Really my only point here was that Diablo is an exception to this rule -- it's a blockbuster, really -- so Blizzard was in the singular position to spend a lot more on development than most companies would be able to, to get all the edge case and development-expensive features in.